# VB 2008 <The system cannot find the reference specified>

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dll

I've created a class library in Visual Studio 2008, and when I try to add the dll as a reference, I get the message in the title for the Path field in my project references. I've been going for a week trying to figure out this issue, and I haven't been able to come up with anything. The strange thing is I can add the same reference to a Visual Studio 2010 project, and it works perfectly fine.

I used VS 2008 to build it because the dll isn't used in house and needs to be compatible with .Net 3.5. Any ideas?

**EDIT: I also found out that referencing the dll in a c# project works fine as well. It's only Visual Basic that's causing me problems.**

Comment: You can set your 2010 VS to build a 3.5 project.

Comment: The people I'm giving the dll to don't have VS 2010. Targeting 3.5 from 2010 was causing the error, so I recreated the project in VS 2008, thinking that I could rule out version issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolution**

Using [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com), I was able to find out that some obscure dll was indirectly being
referenced (IEShims.dll) but couldn't be found. After a little more trial and error, I found my project had a specified reference path (Project Properties -> References -> Reference Paths) that pointed to the project's DEBUG directory. I had to remove that reference path, which then resolved the above issue.

Comment: I resolved my instance of this issue. I discovered that I had different framework targets between my web project and class library project. Changed both of them to Framework 4.5.1 and this cleared up the issue.