# The system cannot find the reference specified for an assembly

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.NET solution which have a few projects and a 'References' folder in the root directory.

Now I want to add a new dll reference to one of the projects from this References folder but getting the following message:

> The system cannot find the reference specified

How can this be solved?

Comment: Is the references path in the project/solution all set correctly?

Comment: Hi Preet, I think that they are, since previous dlls are referenced with correct paths. How do i go about checking this?

Comment: Ok so after a little digging around, this issue pops up only in visual studio 2008. It works in 2010 and 2005. Any help would be great

Comment: set the logging of the build to Diagnostic. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/09/29/475157.aspx, that should tell you where it's probing

Comment: May be a 32/64bit mismatch between the project and the reference

Comment: Have you checked this resource (assuming you have VS2008)?:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473734/vb-2008-the-system-cannot-find-the-reference-specified

Comment: Have you tried adding the DLL to your project file, and then referencing it from that location?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this many times. Here I was trying to execute a jar file when a picturebox was clicked. I added my jar to my resources :

`Private Sub PictureBox9_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles _PictureBox9.Click
        Dim dir As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp
        Dim filename As String = dir + "minecraft.jar" 'Look Below 
        IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, My.Resources.minecraft)
        Process.Start(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "minecraft.jar")
End Sub`

The following worked for other programs though, but not minecraft, :

`Private Sub Panel9_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Panel9.Click
        proc = Process.Start("vbexpress.exe", "") 
End Sub`

*proc was a New System.Diagnostics.Process()

But for actual files, you have manually lure them out of their location.
So I did `Me.Resources.1234.png` which saved me writing the directory. But this still did not work with minecraft, so I kept that long paragraph about in place.